# Convert json to array in python (value,id,value,id....)

Tags: python

Am trying to create an array from json object, I can print the required values but couldn't push them into array in Python, how can I do that?

```
data={"wc":[{"value":8,"id":0},{"value":9,"id":1}]}

dataset = []
test=[]

for i in data['wc']:
    print(i['value'],',',i['id'])
    test=i['value'],i['id']
    dataset.append(test)

print(dataset)
```

Am getting correct values as required but with '(' and ')'
How can I remove them and get final output as

```
[8,0,9,1]
```

Like [value,id,value,id....]

Comment: There is no JSON in this question at all.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about.. Variable data holds the json right?

Comment: No, data contains a perfectly normal Python dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a nested dictionary. Just iterate over the values of the nested dicts:

```
dataset = []
for entry in data['wc']:
    for value in entry.values():
        dataset.append(value)

>>> dataset
[0, 8, 1, 9]
```

with order `value` first `id` second:

```
dataset = []
for entry in data['wc']:
    dataset.extend([entry['value'], entry['id']])
dataset
[0, 8, 1, 9]
```

Comment: hi Mike, Thanks a lot!.. But the problem with this is, it sometimes prints [8,0,9,1].. How can we ensure it gives only [0,8,1,9].. Because, I would send this array as input to mysql stored procedure

Comment: @SathishPanduga The order of the keys is not guranteed in a dict in python. Google hash randomization in python dictionary.

Comment: This is due the fact, that a `dict` is unordered. You can think about using `ordereddict` instead and order the contents on a given criterion.

Comment: @albert I don't think using OrderedDict is possible here, OP is generating the dict from a Json array here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that could be somehow a problem. However, it would solve the problem to have `id` and `value` ordered in the dicts inside the list.

Comment: @SathishPanduga: Do you want to insert the list of `wc` only or could there be even more lists contained in the `data` dict? This would become an important detail when talking about sorted data extraction.

Comment: I couldn't reply as SO is in maintenance for last 40 min..  I can even have a simple dict like [{"value":8,"id":0},{"value":9,"id":1}] ... How can we ensure to have same order like [value,id,value,id, ...... ] ?

Comment: Added a version with order.